# MySQL is not using index for ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have index on `(column_1, column_2, column_3)` and when I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_1 DESC, column_2 ASC, column_3 ASC
```

that index is not used.

I would need that index to be used since there is large difference in query time when I only use `ORDER BY column_1 DESC` (around 0.0005 seconds) and `ORDER BY column_1 DESC, column_2 ASC, column_3 ASC` (around 0.4 seconds).

Also that index is not even used in `ORDER BY column_1 DESC`.

This is `EXPLAIN` for `ORDER BY column_1 DESC, column_2 ASC, column_3 ASC`, same is for only `ORDER BY column_1 DESC`:

[image]

Is there a reason why index is not used?

Comment: `asc` and `desc` make a difference in the index.  It shouldn't but it does.  And, unfortunately, MySQL historically did not support  descending indexes.

Comment: What type of index is it? How many columns do you have in your table?

Comment: @M.Kanarkowski index is BTREE, I have 11 columns in that table but that shouldn't matter if index is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index-definition needs to match the sorting order you are querying, or at least the mixed sorting direction (that is, either `DESC`, `ASC`, `ASC` or `ASC`, `DESC`, `DESC`). The [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-index-use)-docs say:

> If a query mixes ASC and DESC, the optimizer can use an index on the columns **if the index also uses corresponding mixed ascending and descending columns**. [...] The optimizer can use an index on (key_part1, key_part2) if key_part1 is descending and key_part2 is ascending. It can also use an index on those columns (with a backward scan) if key_part1 is ascending and key_part2 is descending.

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html) for more information.

Comment: So the solution would be to create index `(column_1 DESC, column_2, column_3)`? I did that and it's still not used. Maybe it's because these columns are new and there are less than 100 different rows altogether so db engine decided not to use index?

Comment: You may need to `ANALYZE TABLE`. But yes, the optimizer considers the cost of reading the index first and then reading the rows the index points to Vs. just reading the table. If the index is not considered helpful, it's not used. If the table (the whole table?!) has just a few hundret rows, the whole table most likely fits in memory and the benefit from an index is small to begin with.

Comment: Note that defining indexes with a mix of ASC and DESC columns is a new feature in MySQL 8.0. Declaring ASC and DESC in columns of an index is ignored in earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's the problem then, I have version 5.6.41.

Comment: Yeah, in 5.6, you can declare columns of an index as `DESC` but they will only be stored as `ASC`.